# Differentiate $\omega(x,y)=\omega(x,y+\epsilon)$ with respect to $\epsilon$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm trying to read through *Symmetry Methods for Differential Equations* by Peter Hydon. However, I have become stuck on something which looks like it should be very simple. On p. 12 it says (paraphrasing)

> Differentiating
>   $$\omega(x,y)=\omega(x,y+\epsilon)$$
>   with respect to $\epsilon$ at $\epsilon=0$ leads to the result $$\omega_y(x,y)=0.$$

However, I don't understand how to reach that result!

Please let me know if more context is required.

### Edit:

I have tried thinking about it a different way:

Let $z=y+\epsilon$. Then,

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\omega(x,y+\epsilon)}{\partial \epsilon} &= \frac{\partial\omega(x,z)}{\partial \epsilon} \\
&= \frac{\partial\omega(x,z)}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial \epsilon} \\
&= \frac{\partial\omega(x,y+\epsilon)}{\partial (y+\epsilon)} \frac{\partial (y+\epsilon)}{\partial \epsilon} \\
&=\frac{\partial\omega(x,y+\epsilon)}{\partial (y+\epsilon)} (1) \\
\end{align}

Now, taking $\epsilon=0$ yields
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\omega(x,y+0)}{\partial \epsilon} &= \frac{\partial\omega(x,y+0)}{\partial (y+0)} \\
0 &= \frac{\partial\omega(x,y)}{\partial y} \\
\end{align}

Is that valid?

Comment: Taylor-expand $\omega(x,y+\epsilon)$ to first order in $\epsilon$ and see what you get.

Comment: If the context is saying that $\omega(x,y)=\omega(x,y+\epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon$ sufficiently small (this is not explicitly clear), then you literally have only to apply the definition of partial derivative. What got you stuck? Do you not understand some concept, the definition, or something else?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Yes, it is for all $\epsilon$ sufficiently close to zero. I have edited my question with what I hope is a valid approach.

Comment: I think I got stuck because I foolishly didn't realise that I should think of $y+\epsilon$ as a function $z(y,\epsilon)=y+\epsilon$. So... that's embarrassing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have
\begin{align}
\omega(x, y) = \omega(x, y+\varepsilon)
\end{align}
which means $\omega$ doesn't change in the $y$ direction. Anyhow, by chain rule, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\omega(x, y+\epsilon) = \frac{\partial\omega}{\partial y}(x, y+\varepsilon) \frac{d}{d\epsilon}(y+\varepsilon) = \frac{\partial\omega}{\partial y}(x, y+\varepsilon).
\end{align}
Now, set $\varepsilon=0$, we get
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\omega(x, y+\epsilon)\Big|_{\varepsilon=0} = \frac{\partial\omega}{\partial y}(x, y).
\end{align}
On the other hand, using the assumption, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\omega(x, y+\varepsilon) = \frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\omega(x, y) =0.
\end{align}

Comment: In the first line, you write $\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial y}$. Compare this to my edited question where I write $\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial (y+\epsilon)}$. Eventually we reach the same point, because we set $\epsilon=0$. However, are these two approaches completely equivalent?

Comment: @daviewales : You are using $y$ with different meanings. As the argument in $y+ε$ it indicates a specific value. As part of the formal symbol $\frac{∂ω}{∂y}$ it indicates a place, the second argument of $ω$, independent of the actual value of that argument. One could go further in that $$\frac{∂ω}{∂y}(x_0,y_0)=\lim_{ε\to0}\frac{ω(x_0,y_0+ε)-ω(x_0,y_0)}{ε}=0.$$

Comment: @LutzL So, would it be better to use a different variable for a different meaning then?